# Timestamp in Layout Manager

Tags: qgis, print-composer, temporal-controller

I have temporally varying data that I am trying to show as a map in the Layout Manager, which I have done successfully as shown in the left. The intent is not to create a dynamic video, but simply select a specific timestep and plot as a static image.

To modify the timestep shown I just modified the Start in the Temporal Range properties of that map.

Now my question is, is there a way to add a dynamic text in the Layout that would show the timestamp of the map in question?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new point layer, set symbology to `No Symbols` and use it only to create a label. The label's source is the variable  `@map_start_time` - this returns

> The start of the map’s temporal time range (as a datetime value)

From [documentation](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#variables)

Use `@map_end_time` for the end point of the current frame. To get the point in the middle between start- and end-time, you might use  an expression like

```
@map_start_time + 
to_interval (
    second (@map_end_time  - @map_start_time) / 2
)
```

[image]